# Multiline text field JSON to array - SharePoint SPFx

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, spfx, spfx-webparts, react

I'm building a webpart application using SharePoint SPFx with react.

I would like to use SharePoint's multiline text field as a way to store an array. I saw this thread here which said you can convert the array into a JSON to then store as a string.

The goal is to create a updating history list. So for example when someone makes any edits on the front end of my application on submit I want to store it like this:

```
0:
   Action: Updated item number 3
   User: John Smith
   Date: 07/14/2020
1:
   Action: Renamed item 22
   User: Diana Jane
   Date: 07/04/2020
2:
   Action: Removed item 4 and item 15
   User: Eli Perez
   Date: 07/03/2020
```

I myself will create this array I just need help on how to store it to be able to then loop through and display it on another page.

Answer (score 0):

@hisusu32 do you mean how you would write this as a JSON structure, or how you would save in a SharePoint list?

As far as I would write it in JSON:

```
[
  {
    Action: 'Updated item number 3',
    User: 'John Smith',
    Date: '07/14/2020'
  },
  {
    Action: 'Renamed item 22',
    User: 'Diana Jane',
    Date: '07/04/2020'
  },
  {
    Action: 'Removed item 4 and item 15',
    User: 'Eli Perez',
    Date: '07/03/2020'
  }
]
```

Let us know if that's what you're looking for (and next steps) so we can help.

Comment: Hi Hugo, thanks for the response. Yes this helps a bit. I saw with the multi line that you can format with JSON. Basically what I'm trying to do is store my array in a SharePoint List. I was hoping to use the multi line field to store the list. Then in the front end I would make a call to this field, loop through and display. Any ideas on best way to do this?

Comment: Do you mean that you'd like to store the JSON in a single multiline field in a list? Keep in mind that you're limited to 63,999 characters in a multiline field for lists (but unlimited in document libraries -- go figure).

If I were doing this, I'd break each element of my JSON into individual list items, and use something like PnPjs to retrieve the list content and map each field to a serialized array.

Something like this:
```typescript
export interface IAction {
  Action: string;
  User: string;
  Data: string; // maybe use date here?
}
```

Comment: Then in your method where you retrieve your content, I'd return a:
```typescript
const actions: IAction[];
```

Let me know if that's something you'd like to do and I can throw some sample code together.

I hope this helps?

Comment: Ah thank you for this amazing information. This is very helpful. Can you go ahead and throw up some sample code to get me started I would appreciate that. I'm familiar with `PnPjs` I think my biggest concern is I need this field to append so when a new action comes in it doesn't erase/update what is currently in that list item, but adds to it.